# Compare/classify equal-length strings in a Wordle-like manner?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a word guessing application (like Wordle).
Let's assume I have a predefined word

```
let predefinedWord = "apple";
```

I want to make a function to compare with the predefined word.

```
const compare = (word) => {
  // compare the guess with the predefined word apple
}

let myGuess = "alley"
const result = compare(myGuess); // compare apple with alley
// return 
// ["Matched", "Included", "Included", "Included", "Not Matched"]
```

How can I make the function like this?

Comment: The [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods), [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods), [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) classes, along with [text formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting) techniques are all you need to make a function like this. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Note that matches that are “included” shouldn’t be duplicated. `ALLEY` should produce “Included” for the first L and “Not Matched” for the second L. Are you sure that’s what you need?

Comment: @Sebastian is right, also for an example where the user would provide one or more `P`s when comparing to `apple`.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon how can I do that logic?

Comment: @CCCC I would pass through the guessed string twice: the first time to list all Matched letters, the second time to list all Included letters. Each time a letter is found (Matched or Included), remove the letter from both the guessed word and the actual word. This works best when converting both strings into an array using `Array.from` and then setting the index to `null`, for example, to keep the indexes the same. Then iterate through the guessed string one last time, but only checking if a match has been found at this index or if an included letter has been found at this index.

Comment: @CCCC please post your final solution here (assuming you're going to implement the above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the word length is as short as in wordle, a direct approach works well:

```js
let predefinedWord = "apple";
let predefArr = predefinedWord.split('');


const compare = (predef,word) => {
  return word
         .split('')
         .map( (letter,i) => {
           if (predef[i] === letter) return "Matched";
           if (predef.includes(letter)) return "Included";
           return "Not Matched"
         });
  
}

let myGuess = "alley"
const result = compare(predefArr, myGuess); // compare apple with alley
// return 
// ["Matched", "Included", "Included", "Included", "Not Matched"]

console.log(result)
```

EDIT: This answers the original question:

> ```
> let myGuess = "alley"
> const result = compare(myGuess); // compare apple with alley
> // return 
> // ["Matched", "Included", "Included", "Included", "Not Matched"]
> ```
>
> How can I make the function like this?

And it is **not** the behaviour of the game wordle

Comment: @Arjan i've added an edit to clarify that

Comment: `compare(['b','b','b','b','a'], 'aaaab');` returns `[ "Included", "Included", "Included", "Included", "Included" ]` which doesn't align with Wordle logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
const compare = (word) => {
  let result = [];
  for(let i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    if(predefinedWord.includes(word[i])){
      result.push(predefinedWord.indexOf(word[i]) === i?"Matched":"Included")
    }else{
      result.push("Not Matched")
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: While this indeed does comply with what was asked, it's still incorrect. See the comments below the question.